# How do I check if a certain index in a jEditorPane contains a character that is bolded, italicized, or underlined?

Tags: java, swing, richtext, jeditorpane

I've made a program that loads a text document into a jEditorPane. Some of the text in the document is bolded, italicized, or underlined, and I want to know how to check if a particular index in the text contains one of these three attributes. For instance, if I store the first character of the text in a variable as follows:

```
char chr = jEditorPane1.getDocument().getText(0, 1).charAt(0);
```

How do I then check if the character in *chr* has been bolded, italicized, or underlined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StyledDocument doc = (StyledDocument)jEditorPane1.getDocument()
Element textElem = doc.getCharacterElement(offset);
StyleConstants.isBold(textElem.getAttributes());
StyleConstants.isItalic(textElem.getAttributes());
```

Alternatively if caret is positioned in the offset you can get InputAttributes from the kit.

```
AttributeSet attrs = ((StyledEditorKit)jEditorPane1.getEditorKit()).getInputAttributes();
StyleConstants.isBold(attrs);
```